# Material Design Lite and jQuery, something is wrong with smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, material-design-lite

Yesterday, I asked similar question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035052/material-design-lite-and-jquery-smooth-scroll-not-working).

And smooth scroll has worked.
However, something is wrong with smooth scroll when I used it.

Code is here ( this repository include 1 html file and 1 image file):
https://github.com/MitsuhikoShimomura/mdl-error

Some important parts of the code.
Smooth Scroll:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("a.smooth").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var speed = 500;
            var href= $(this).attr("href");
            var target = $(href == "#" || href == "" ? 'html' : href);
            var nav_height = $(".mdl-layout__header-row").height();
            var position = target.offset().top - nav_height;
            $(".mdl-layout__content").animate({scrollTop:position}, speed, "swing");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Body contents:

```
<div class="layout-transparent mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--transparent">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
            <span class="mdl-layout-title">Sample</span>
            <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
            <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link smooth" href="#0">0</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link smooth" href="#1">1</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link smooth" href="#2">2</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link smooth" href="#3">3</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link smooth" href="#4">4</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!--Main contents -->
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <ul class="ul-test">
            <li id="0">0</li>
            <li id="1">1</li>
            <li id="2">2</li>
            <li id="3">3</li>
            <li id="4">4</li>
        </ul>
    </main>
</div>
```

Correct Scroll
---When smooth scroll starts from "top", scroll works correct.
---However if the goal of scroll is "top", scroll works correct.

- From "top" to "#1"
- From "top" to "#3"
- From "#2" to "top"
- etc..

Incorrect Scroll
---When smooth scroll dose not start from "top", scroll dosen't work correct.
---When leaving position and arriving position are same, scroll dosen't work incorrect.

- From "#1" to "#2"
- From "#2" to "#4"
- From "#3" to "#3"
- etc..

I have no idea why smooth scroll do not work correct.

Comment: I think you should add important parts of the code directly to your question.

Comment: @m02ph3u5
Thanks! I updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution of this problem is here:
http://qiita.com/gonshi_com/items/33ac3df3ed98352c96b6#comment-87ad66f44229688fb638

jQuery's ".offset()" cannot get correct position with "zoom" property of css.

Solution is this:

```
var target = $( '#target' ).offset().top;
```

↓

```
var target = $( '#target' ).get( 0 ).offsetTop
```

Answer (score 0):

Mitsuhiko Shimomura had the correct answer I just wanted to combine the code together for more clarity. I had to add  `- 130`  to the  `.offsetTop` because the smooth scroll was going past my target id's in the html. Thank you for the help! See my [app](http://www.ianposton.com/resume/index.php) where I used this smoothscroll feature.

And remember to add smooth class to anchors in html like this

```
<a class="smooth" href="#scrollToId">Target</a> 
<div id="scrollToId">Target</div>

$(function(){
    $('a.smooth').click(function(){
        console.log("SMOOTH BEGIN");
        var speed = 1000;
        var href= $(this).attr("href");
        var target = $(href == "#" || href == "" ? 'html' : href);
        var position = target.get( 0 ).offsetTop - 130;
        $(".mdl-layout__content").animate({scrollTop:position}, speed, "swing");
        console.log("SMOOTH END");
    });
});
```